# Gitlab CI: How do I use the environment variable from one stage as needs:project ref in another

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have two jobs in the same project: `job A` and `job B`.

`job A` creates an environment variable `EXTERNAL_PROJ_REF=some_tag` and exports it through a `.env` file.

`job B` needs to download artifacts from an `external_project` and package them with other artifacts from the current project. I want to be able to dynamically choose the commit reference from which these external artifacts get downloaded. I am trying to use the environment variable `EXTERNAL_PROJ_REF` as the `ref` for `external_project` needed by `job B`.

```
job A:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "EXTERNAL_PROJ_REF=`./generate_variable.sh`" > build.env  # evaluates to EXTERNAL_PROJ_REF=some_tag
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env

job B:
  stage: package
  script:
    - ./do_packaging_job.sh
  needs:
    - job: job A
      artifacts: true
    - project: external_project
      ref: $EXTERNAL_PROJ_REF
      job: external_job
      artifacts: true
```

When I run this pipeline though, `job B` instantly fails with the following error:

> This job depends on other jobs with expired/erased artifacts:

If I hardcode `ref` to `some_tag`, the job does not fail, and I can confirm the `EXTERNAL_PROJ_REF` is successfully passed to `job B`.

```
job B:
  stage: package
  script:
    - echo "Ref = $EXTERNAL_PROJ_REF"  # Correctly prints "Ref = some_tag"
    - ./do_packaging_job.sh
  needs:
    - job: job A
      artifacts: true
    - project: external_project
      ref: some_tag   # hardcoded so the job doesn't fail
      job: external_job
      artifacts: true
```

However, when I have `ref:$EXTERNAL_PROJ_REF`, the pipeline fails. Can somebody tell me if I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally realized Gitlab does not support what I want to do, at least not this way. According to [this link](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/index.html#pass-an-environment-variable-to-another-job), a variable passed from a different job can only be used in `before_script`, `script` or `after_script` sections of a job; it cannot be used to configure jobs. I cannot use it the `needs` section of `job B`.

Luckily, I found a simple workaround using the [Gitlab API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/). I have API access to `external_project`, so I just use `wget` to download the artifact I need from the dynamically selected commit reference. Afterwards, I directly pass the artifact to `job B`.

```
job A:
  stage: build
  script:
    # Dynamically create commit reference
    - EXTERNAL_PROJ_REF=`./generate_commit_ref.sh`
    # Download artifact with Gitlab API
    - wget --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:${EXTERNAL_PROJ_TOKEN}" --output-document outputFileName.file "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${EXTERNAL_PROJ_ID}/jobs/artifacts/${EXTERNAL_PROJ_REF}/raw/${EXTERNAL_ARTIFACT_PATH}?job=${EXTERNAL_JOB_NAME}"
    # btw CI_API_V4_URL is a gitlab defined variable
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - outputFileName.file

job B:
  stage: package
  script:
    - ./do_packaging_job.sh
  needs:
    # Now this packaging job only needs job A. It doesn't need the external job anymore
    - job: job A
      artifacts: true
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution I use for sharing variables between two GitLab CI jobs:

```
stages:
 - build
 - package
 
job A:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "EXTERNAL_PROJ_REF=`./generate_variable.sh`" > build.env
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build.env

job B:
  stage: package
  before_script:
    - export $(cat build.env | xargs)
  script:
    - ./do_packaging_job.sh
```

Comment: Thanks @Davide,

With my current code, the variable is available in the `script` and even the `before_script`. The problem appears when I use it in `needs`. It acts like the variable doesn't exist. The artifacts from `needs` are downloaded before `job B` runs its scripts, so I can't use your solution :(